# Wordpress site showing white screen after deleting wp-cache plugin

Tags: php, caching, wordpress

I have a website that has a plugin named `wp-cache` now wp-cache has known security issues so I decided to delete it.

After disabling and deleting using wordpress admin interface, the screen just went white and the website is not working anymore.

I tried deleting using FTP, and renaming, all with the same result.

I also tried following the steps to fix "white screen of death" but it didn't help. (https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/wordpress-white-screen-of-death/ and http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/common-wordpress-errors-with-solutions/)

Is this a known bug with wp-cache plugin? How to solve this issue with wordpress?

**UPDATE:**
I found this on their README.txt

> = I removed WP-Cache and now Wordpress does not work =
>
> This occurs because Wordpress still try to run `advanced-cache.php`. Remove the following line to you wp-config.php` file:
>
> ```
>     define('WP_CACHE', true);
> ```

I  followed their instruction by commenting out the code `define('WP_CACHE', true)`, now wp-admin is working fine but the website is still showing white page.

**UPDATE:**
Ahh, it's all working now. The answer on their readme file solved the problem. The problem that came up after it's fixed is because of the other plugins; it has all been disabled because I followed the solution to fix white screen earlier. I enabled the needed plugins and now it is working.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: You have a fatal error in your page most likely. Probably something is trying to call a class, method, or other that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Check your php error logs

Answer (score 0):

There could still be references to the plug-in in your `wp-config.php` file.